# Bash prompt not recognizing variables

Tags: bash, terminal, iterm

I'm customizing my bash prompt (I use iTerm on OS X Lion), and have tried something like:

```
PS1='\n[\u]-> '
```

Just for simplicity, but after reloading my `~/.bash_profile`, my prompt now says:

```
\n[\u]->
```

and not what I'm expecting to (a new line, followed by my username).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `chsh`, might work on Mac as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the shell being invoked? If it's as `sh`, or possibly other ways, it won't be interpreted. Try `echo $0`

Comment: What about `echo $SHELL`? ;) ... okay okay, I get it ... `$0` is for lazy people.

Comment: I played with zsh this weekend, but I'd like to just use bash. That's my problem, I think. When I ran `echo $0`, it returned `-zsh`.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Actually, I tested and they gave different results. `$0` was `sh`, `$SHELL` was `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @cnnr Yep, that'll do it. I'm not on my Mac so I'm not sure how to change it, but it should be the same way you changed it to `zsh` in the first place.

Comment: @Kevin: interesting, thanks for the info. That's a little odd actually, but still good to know.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, @Kevin `$0` is the current shell, `$SHELL` is the default shell. If you run a script with `#!/bin/sh` at the start, `$0` will be `sh`, but `$SHELL` will still be the user’s default. (Actually, `$0` is whatever name was used to invoke the current process, which may be, for example, the name of a symbolic link that refers to the program—`pico` actually runs `nano`—or `-bash` if bash is invoked as a login shell.)

Comment: @Chris: that's not entirely true and may be limited to interactive shells. For scripts `$0` is the script name, not the name of the process - which would still be the interpreter and not the script.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: Sure, but we were specifically discussing the difference between `$0` and `$SHELL` from an interactive shell (you yourself wrote, “`$0` is the current shell” without distinguishing the case of a subshell running a script). I was just trying to provide a better explanation of the specifically mentioned behaviors without explaining how the Unix kernel works. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Notice the single quotes in your prompt? [Bash syntax](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-quoting.html) treats single and double quotes differently. Use double quotes to allow the shell to expand the special chars.

Also, do you have `promptvars` set?

Comment: Not really in this case. It's not classic variables, it's "special" variables. I thought it was this as well until I tried.

Comment: Nope, the variable is set the same with single or double, and it's not interpreted until it's about to be printed.

Comment: @Kevin I'm aware that interpretation happens at print time. But [according to this](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html) and the BASH man page, the prompt *does* go through quote expansion.

Comment: Eventually, but setting with `''` vs `""` has no effect because that's not where it's expanded. Try it yourself: `PS1="\n> "; echo $PS1; PS1='\n> '; echo $PS1`

Comment: Point of terminology: these aren’t variables. They aren’t expanded by any shell expansion phase. Each time the prompt is displayed, these are interpreted, and then expansion phases are performed before displaying the final prompt. (These are described by the bash man page as “backslash-escaped special characters”.)

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the single quotes with double quotes, i.e. `PS1="\n[\u]-> "`.

Comment: Nope, once the variable is set it doesn't matter, and the escapes aren't interpreted until the prompt is about to be written.